# Convert time with format HH:MM AM/PM to HH:MM:SS

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am use PHP and MySQL. How can I convert time with format HH:MM AM/PM to HH:MM:SS to save time to MySQL?

Comment: What is the type of your original time variable?

Comment: Example for you: `$time = '10:12 AM'; echo $time; echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($time));`

Comment: my input is text but with format HH:MM AM/PM

Comment: @PleaseWait - You would need to use `H:i:s`. `m` is for month.

Comment: @NathanDawson thank you! I noticed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strtotime` to convert it to a timestamp and then format that using the `date` function.

Example below assumes `$time` has been set to the time you need to format.

```
$time = date( "H:i:s", strtotime( $time ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is:

```
<?php
    $date = "6:23 AM";
    $timeType = explode(" ", $date);
    $timeItems = explode(":", $timeType[0]);
    if($timeType[1] == "PM"){
        $timeItems[0] += 12;
    }
    $time = implode(":", $timeItems);
    $time .= ":00";
    var_dump($time);
?>
```

Comment: This would work but you're reinventing the wheel. There are already functions baked into PHP to handle dates.

Comment: Yea that's my bad  I hadn't realized that you could just grab the time using the date function. Learning from answering

Answer (score 0):

Use [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to resolve your problem:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i:%s')
```

Comment: MySQL date_format and time_format don't recognize am/pm strings.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. In MySQL use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i:%s');
```

And using your example you could couple this with [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('09:41 AM', '%h:%i %p'), '%H:%i:%s');
```

Then in your MySQL query you could substitute the `09:41 AM` with a variable based on your MySQL table.